# How to get the coefficients in Lasso Regression at every split while performing 10 fold cross validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, lasso-regression

I am doing Randomized search cv to find alpha value in Lasso Regression and I am performing 10 fold cross validation. Is there a way to get the coefficients value for every split, just like we get the scores by using cv_results function?

Comment: @MustafaAydın I believe the OP wants the `coef_` of the fitted `Lasso` estimators in each iteration. This cannot be retrieved from the `cv_results_` since not all fitted estimators are saved. Provided a workaround in my answer.

Comment: @afsharov Oh, thanks, I see now and thanks for the answer, +1.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to do this via `RandomizedSearchCV`. But you can work around this by defining your own class that e.g. prints the coefficients to the console when the predict function is called:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso


class MyLasso(Lasso):

    def predict(self, X):
        print(self.coef_)
        return super().predict(X)
```

`MyLasso` behaves the same as `Lasso` and can be used as usual:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, RandomizedSearchCV


X, y = make_regression(n_features=5, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

param_distributions = {'alpha': [0.01, 0.1, 1]}
rs = RandomizedSearchCV(
    MyLasso(),
    param_distributions=param_distributions,
    cv=2,
    n_iter=3,
    random_state=42
)

rs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Output for the example above (three iterations of 2-fold cross-validation gives six results):

```
[64.57650818 98.64237403 57.07123743 60.56898095 35.59985227]
[64.57001187 98.63679695 57.06557977 60.56304163 35.59888746]
[64.43774582 98.55938568 57.01219706 60.49221968 35.51151313]
[64.37690435 98.49805298 56.95345309 60.43375789 35.5018112 ]
[63.05012223 97.72950224 56.42179336 59.72460697 34.62812171]
[62.44582912 97.11061327 55.83218634 59.14092054 34.53104869]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to me that saving the coefficients as additional scores would be slicker than modifying the estimator itself as in [@afsharov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984035/10495893).  Defining a scorer and passing it to the search as

```py
def coefs_scorer(estimator, X, y):
    return estimator.coef_

rs = RandomizedSearchCV(
    ...
    scoring={'r2': 'r2', 'coefs': coefs_scorer},
    refit='r2',
)
```

fails because there's a check that scorers return single numbers.  So you need to unpack the coefficients, and I ended up with this:

```py
def coefs_scorer(estimator, X, y, i):
    return estimator.coef_[i]

from functools import partial
scoring = {'r2': 'r2'}
for i in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    scoring[f'coef{i}'] = partial(coefs_scorer, i=i)

param_distributions = {'alpha': [0.01, 0.1, 1]}
rs = RandomizedSearchCV(
    Lasso(),
    param_distributions=param_distributions,
    cv=2,
    n_iter=3,
    random_state=42,
    scoring=scoring,
    refit='r2',
)
```

Note that with multiple metrics you need to specify which to use for refitting.  Because of all the additional work, I'm not so sure this is better than the custom class.  It does have a few advantages though:

- If you wanted to pickle the best estimator, you don't need to package-ize the custom class.
- The scores are programmatically saved rather than just printed.
- Since they're scores, you get the average and standard deviation of the coefficients across folds stored in `cv_results_` (of course, calculating them yourself wouldn't be difficult).

Disadvantages:

- We had to specify a metric per feature.  It's ugly, but worse it assumes you know in advance the number of features (it would fail if your estimator was a pipeline that had a feature selection or certain feature engineering steps).
- If you return train scores, you'll duplicate the coefficients in `cv_results_`.
- These aren't actually scores, so semantically this is hacky.
- The scorer assumes that `coef_` exists and is one-dimensional.